# Can i use hybrid_property with joinedload in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have sqlalchemy models:

```
class Equipment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'equipment'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ports = db.relationship('SnmpPort', passive_deletes=True, backref='Equipment')


class SnmpPort(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'snmp_ports'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    equipment = Column('equipment', Integer, ForeignKey('equipment.id'))

    @property
    def Link(self):
        if self.Link1 is not None:
            return self.Link1
        if self.Link2 is not None:
            return self.Link2
        return None

    @property
    def ToSnmpPort(self):
        if self.Link:
            if self.Link.portid1 == self.id:
                return self.Link.SnmpPort2
            else:
                return self.Link.SnmpPort1
        return None


class Link(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'link'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    portid1 = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('snmp_ports.id'))
    SnmpPort1 = relation('SnmpPort', foreign_keys=portid1,
                     backref=backref("Link1", uselist=False))
    portid2 = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('snmp_ports.id'))
    SnmpPort2 = relation('SnmpPort', foreign_keys=portid2,
                     backref=backref("Link2", uselist=False))
    active = Column(Boolean, default=True)
```

Now i have to write queries like this:

```
equipment = Equipment.query\
    .options(joinedload_all(Equipment.ports, SnmpPort.Link1, Link.SnmpPort1))\
    .options(joinedload_all(Equipment.ports, SnmpPort.Link2, Link.SnmpPort1))\
    .options(joinedload_all(Equipment.ports, SnmpPort.Link2, Link.SnmpPort2))\
    .options(joinedload_all(Equipment.ports, SnmpPort.Link2, Link.SnmpPort1))\
    .get(3097)

for port in equipment.ports:
    print port.ToSnmpPort
```

When i want to add more joins i have to add it four times, can i avoid it?
Can i use hybrid_property to write queries like this:

```
equipment = Equipment.query\
    .options(joinedload_all(Equipment.ports, SnmpPort.Link, Link.SnmpPort1))\
    .options(joinedload_all(Equipment.ports, SnmpPort.Link, Link.SnmpPort2))\
    .get(3097)
```

Is it possible to use the short queries or even shorter if do some tricks with Link.SnmpPort1/2?

Comment: I don't see why not. But in your case, you're just using `property` so it won't work. You'll need to use [`hybrid_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_property) as here and you'll probably also need to set the `expression`

Comment: I was trying to realize it but i could not. I don't know what should i write in expression method.

Comment: The expression method is supposed to contain the analogous SQL expression in SQLAlchemy format for what you want to achieve under the hybrid_property. In all fairness, you could even consider using [`column_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property)

Comment: Stil can not find the solution to use model in expression. Could you write an example of code?